# Single sign on for an android application using device capability

Tags: android, single-sign-on

looking for a solution for the below scenario,
we have two android application(developed by different vendor) and each application is using its own api and user details to authenticate(basic authentication with userid and password) the users. We need to implement the single sign on for these 2 applications.

If I logged-in into application A, then when I launch Application B it should automatically sign in with that user (userid and pwd in both the application is same) in application B when launched.

passing the token in the url and do backend verification can be an option.

But, we are looking for a solution in which the identity can be stored/managed in the device once it is logged-in into app A, then when we launch app B, it can use the authenticated details and sign-in with that user.

thanks in advance.